# Trying to trace out the solution, what function does this program compute?

Tags: complexity-theory, theory

```
  IF X ≠ 0 GOTO A
  Z ← Z + 1
  IF Z ≠ 0 GOTO B
[A] X ← X – 1
  Y ← Y + 1
  IF X ≠ 0 GOTO A
[B] Y ← Y + 1
  Y ← Y + 1
  Y ← Y + 1
```

I came up with y = x+4 due to y being compounded 4 times. This could be wrong.

Comment: What's the input?

Comment: There is no input given. Only instructed to find the function the program computes. From Complexity and Languages by Davis, Sigal, Weyuker.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it is some function `y(x,z)` since `Y` is the only value that is assigned but not used in conditionals. I also assume that `X` must be a natural number, otherwise this function will enter an infinite loop (try `X = -1`).

---

```
1:   IF X ≠ 0 GOTO A
2:   Z ← Z + 1
3:   IF Z ≠ 0 GOTO B
4: [A] X ← X – 1
5:   Y ← Y + 1
6:   IF X ≠ 0 GOTO A
7: [B] Y ← Y + 1
8:   Y ← Y + 1
9:   Y ← Y + 1
```

`Y` is always incremented 3 times by lines 7-8, so `Y` must be at least 3.

=> `y = 3 + ...`

**Assume `x > 0, z = n`:**

Line 1 jumps to line 4, and increments `Y` `X` times (decrements `X` and then loops while `X >= 0`, line 4-6). Therefore `Y` must be at least `X`.

=> `y = x + 3`

**Assume `x = 0`:**

In this case, line 1 falls through to line 2. `Z` is incremented from it's initial value and then checked. If `Z` is not equal to zero, `Y = 3` (by lines 3, 7-9). If `Z` is equal to zero, which implies an initial value of `Z = -1`, then `Y = X + 3` (line 3 falls through to lines 4-9).

---

**Therefore** this function (if of the form `y(x,z)`) is a piece wise function of the following form:

`y(x,y) = {3 if Z = -1, X + 3 otherwise}, such that X is an element of the natural numbers.`

---

Note that this is only a guess. Without defined input and outputs (as you say the book does not indicate), they are up for interpretation.